# AccountShare UserOrGroup.Type returning weird results

Tags: sharing, territory-management, public-group, territory, accountshare

I was wondering if someone could explain this to me. I am currently working in an org with Territory Management (1.0) enabled and I am trying running queries but getting weird results.

When I run a query like this:

```
Select Id From AccountShare WHERE UserOrGroup.Type = 'Territory'
```

I get no results back.

However, if I do this:

```
Select Id From Group WHERE Type = 'Territory' //Take an Id from this result set

Select Id,UserOrGroup.Type From AccountShare WHERE UserOrGroupId =: fromPreviousResult
```

I get records back. Now the weird part is, `UserOrGroup.Type` returned in the AccountShare query says `Queue` even though the Id from the `Group` query is clearly a type of `Territory`. Is there something I am missing

Answer (score 0):

`UserOrGroup` field is a polymorphic reference field most probably that is the reason. When using a polymorphic field; `polymorphicfield.type` in where clause returns the object type.

so

`WHERE UserOrGroup.Type =` will return either `User` or `Group`

so your query should be like below:

`SELECT Id
FROM AccountShare
WHERE UserOrGroup.Type='Group' AND UserOrGroupId IN
    (
    Select Id From Group WHERE Type = 'Territory'
    )`

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_filtering_polymorphic_relationships.htm

Comment: I'm not understanding why `Queue` would be returned. It's not a `Queue` to begin with

Comment: Do you have a sharing rule that shares account's with a queue?

Comment: Queues are not supported for accounts. Also this is about Territory Management

Comment: Correct they are not supported. Well I cannot think of anything else.